# Return an object as readonly

Tags: objective-c, properties

How would you return an object from a method, so it is read-only for the caller?
Please note that this isn't a property that can be simply set to read-only when it's getter is declared

i.e `@property(nonatomic,retain,readonly) NSDate* pub_date;`

For example:

```
-(SomeClass*)getObject
{
  SomeClass* object = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
  //Don't allow writing to 'object'
  return object;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what the object is. If it has a mutable / immutable pair (like `NSString`/ `NSMutableString`) then your getter method can return the immutable version.

Otherwise, you can't control the behaviour of other objects - once you've returned an object, there is no control over it from the object that originally provided it.

If you are concerned that another object may alter an object returned from a getter, and thereby amend the property held within the original object, then you should return a copy of the object instead.

Example:

Object A has a mutable string property, object B asks for this mutable string, the getter directly returns the instance variable backing the property.

Object B then changes the string - the property of object A has also been amended because both objects have a pointer to the same mutable string.

In this case, you would return a copy of the object rather than the object itself. If your object is a custom one, you must implement the `NSCopying` protocol to allow this.

A further note - declaring a property as read only simply means that no setter accessor will be generated - i.e. `objectA.property = newValue;` will result in a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up, same goes for @Vladimir, So when setting a property to readonly, i can retrive that property, retain it, and then i can change it? just not directly?

Comment: You _could_, I suppose, but it would be pretty poor practice. When I use read only properties it is typically because I want the convenience of an accessor for something that is derived internally in the object rather than for direct access to an actual ivar.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: there's no simple way of doing this.

Longer answer: Apple's framework defines a sort of standard for its collection classes where the immutable collection is the base class and the mutable collection is the inheriting class. So, for example, NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray. You can follow that standard, and have methods that return MyClass to clients while using MyMutableClass inside them. Technically the client can still send the mutating messages, of course, but IMHO that's not a big risk (after all, the client doesn't know your implementation details).

There are other, more complicated options - you can use pointer swizzling, or subclass and override all mutating methods, or simply copy the mutable class into an immutable counterpart (that's not complicated but may incur a performance hit). But for best results you should probably follow Apple's example.